# Retrieve Mongo documents by index and with a specific limit

Tags: java, mongodb, caching

I have a collection with over 31,000 docs and I want to retrieve x number of docs for each call from my Java `HTTP`(I use a service) call:

```
public void sendGet()throws Exception{
        //using find service to get all nodes
        String url = "service url"; // "http:....."
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        //200 -OK
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        IterationForDocuments+=100; // set to 0;
    }
```

for each call I want to get docs [1-100]  and for the next call I want to get [101-200] and so on until the end.
My questions are: 1 - is there a good way to `cache` 100 doc in java `data-types`. 2- where should I put my index track service(mongo) or the java class?
Here is the mongo query I use :

```
module.exports = function (app, options) {
    var mongoFind = {
        events: mongoFindEvents,

        find: function (req, res) {
            var name = "node"
            var query = {};
            query = req.query;
            var Collection = getCollection(name);
            Collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                res.send(docs);
            });
        }
    };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing how you actually query your MongoDb in this snippet, but what you'll need to do is send a query parameters for the set of documents you wish to retrieve. Then in the code that actually queries MongoDb you need to use the  `limit` and and `skip` operators to pull the correct data. So you're HTTP request object will look like (in JSON format):

```
{
    User-Agent: <user-agent>
    Skip: ### //ie 100, 200, 300, etc
    Limit: ### //Sounds like you always want this to be 100
}
```

Then in your query (again, you didn't show the code that actually queries Mongo, so I'm just writing this as it would look in the Mongo shell):

```
db.collection.find(<query>).skip(request.skip).limit(request.limit)
```

Comment: Any chance that you know the part I need to add to my service?